# Python KeyboardInterrupt button

Tags: python, linux, keyboardinterrupt

I'm using red hat 5 linux, and I would like to know what key combination raises a KeyboardInterrupt exception in python 2.6. I know that it is Ctrl+ c under windows.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's still <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Or you could send a `SIGINT` to the process.